# It is possible to pick an attribute "height" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, attributes, scale

I just want to use a height in an image set up in CSS, then catch this gradation in JS and scale the width to the height x2.25.

Is it possible?

Comment: Try [`Element#clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) or [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Thanks it work with Element#clientHeight !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to set style or [set attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

In this example I set style directly

```js
const imgEl = document.querySelector('img')
console.log('imgEl height:', imgEl.getAttribute('height'))

const divEl = document.querySelector('div#d1')
divEl.style.width = String(+imgEl.getAttribute('height') * 2.25) + 'px'
```

```css
#d1, #d2 {
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img height="150" width="150" src="https://picsum.photos/150/150" />
<div id="d1">div1</div>
<br/>
<div id="d2">div2</div>
```

Comment: I try this : 
``` 
    <img src="./wlts/wlts0.png" alt="" id="wlts"> ```
____________________________________________________________
``` 
    #wlts {
        height: 100px;
    } ```
________________________________________________________________________________________
``` var multiplicateur = 10;
var hauteur = document.getElementById("wlts").clientHeight
var largeur = hauteur*multiplicateur
document.getElementById("wlts").style.width = largeur + "px" ```

This work perfectly !